# How to use RSelenium to drive a browser and move within a map application?

Tags: html, r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to use `RSelenium` to navigate this online map application (https://www.dsec.gov.mo/gis/unidade/unidade.html?lang=en). In the browser, I can either press arrow keys or hold the left-click key and drag to move the map area on display.

However, I haven't been able to replicate the same maneuvers through an `RSelenium` Firefox driver. Here's what I've attempted so far.

```r
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port = 4542L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.dsec.gov.mo/gis/unidade/unidade.html?lang=en")

# unable to scroll the window (no scrolling bar in the outermost window though)
remDr$executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, -50)")

# locate what seems to be container of the map
webElem <- remDr$findElement("tag name", "canvas")
webElem$highlightElement()

webElem$click()
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "down_arrow")) 
webElem$executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", args = list("")) # nothing happens
```

Observing how the html script changes during panning operation in the browser, I noticed that  the attribute `data-interacting` switches from `false` to `true` and reverts to `false` when panning is finished.

```
<div class="esri-view-surface esri-view-surface--inset-outline esri-view-surface--touch-none" role="application" tabindex="0" data-cursor="crosshair" data-interacting="false"><canvas style="width: 982px; height: 804px; display: block;" width="982" height="804"></canvas></div>
```

I'm not familiar with website architecture or Javascript. Any insight on how to navigate this map through R would be much appreciated.

Comment: `down_arrow`, `home`, `end` button won't work on this page. I was only able to press the `+` and `-` symbols on the page.

Comment: On my PC, when the map is "activated", I can press the `up arrow` and other arrow keys to navigate within the map.

Comment: Sure you can press the `up arrow` but i think we can't press the `up arrow` through `RSelenium`

Comment: Is this an issue specific to RSelenium that pressing the `up arrow` cannot be simulated? What about Selenium in general?

Comment: For Selenium i think we can press the up arrow

Comment: Wanted to make a correction, we can press `up_arrow` and `down_arrow` in RSelenium but wasn't able do it for the link in question.

Comment: That's right. It seems that I couldn't correctly locate the "container" of the map application so that I can send key strokes (`up_arrow`, `down_arrow`, etc) to that web element.